# Query Firestore collection on map

Tags: arrays, kotlin, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I have database of `Workspaces` with members and some other data. For each workspace there is a members Map, where key is the UserId and value is the email

It is structured like this:

```
\Workspace01
--- name: 
--- color: 
--- members:
------ userid: "email@email.com"
```

I am trying to query workspaces where the current user is a members.

In Security Rules for instance, I can try something like

```
allow read if uid in resource.members.keys()
```

and it works fine (I think). It allows read, etc.

However, if I try to query the same thing, for instance in kotlin/android, it gives a permission error:
`collection.whereArrayContains("members.keys", uid )`

I have also tried `FieldPath.of()`, or `whereNotEqual("members[uid]", null)`, still the same thing.
I also tried using emails as keys and uid as values... Obviously no difference

There also was a suggestion of using `orderBy("memebers.uid")`. That also gives a "bad permission". However, this orderBy query works just fine in the Firebase console

I am completely out of ideas.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the `members` field is a `map`, so it makes sense that you can't query it with `whereArrayContains`.

If you want to check if the `uid` subfield has a specific value, that'd be:

```
collection.whereEqualTo("members.theUidValue", "theEmailValue")
```

I'm not entirely sure that your security rules will allow this, so I'd start with more relaxed rules to first see if the query works.

---

If you want to simply check whether the UID exists, that isn't possible on a map structure. To allow that, add an additional array field with just the UID values from the map (e.g. `memberUIDs`), and then query with `whereArrayContains` on that.

Comment: That is how I went about it in the end. I'm feeling kinda stupid for asking in the first place :))) I used `whereNotEqualTo("field", "")`. Data is structured so that there shouldn't  be an empty value for a key, so that worked. Thanx!